# Can we craft a Hamiltonian such that the measurement is consistent with the discrete measurement taught in Quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, measurement-problem

So the way I understand this, the way measurement is taught is that

you have a wave function $\Psi(t)$. It's evolution over time is :
$$i \hbar \frac{d}{d t}\vert\Psi(t)\rangle = \hat H(t)\vert\Psi(t)\rangle$$

If you have an observable $\hat{O}$ it defines a basis of the Hilbert space s.t.
$$ \Psi(t) = \sum e_k O_k(t)$$
where $O_k$ are the eigenstates, $e_k$ the eigenvalues.
If you measure $\hat{O}$ in the real world, you will read the results $O_k$ with probability $\frac{e_k^2}{\sum_j e_j^2}$.

The question is, can we craft $\hat{H}$ such that the evolution of $\psi$ converges towards $O_k$ as the $O_k$ become attractors of the solutions of Schrödinger's equation. If we craft $\hat H(t)$ correctly we can have the size of the regions of attractor $O_k$ be $\frac{e_k^2}{\sum_j e_j^2}$ to respect the "discrete" view of measurement.

Is such a Hamiltonian findable ? Have I missed something glaringly obvious ?

Ps: I'm not a physicist.

Comment: Are you imposing additional conditions to make the $O_k$ attractors?

Comment: Do we need to ? To the best of my knowledge I don't think there is. I imagine there would be sort of a time constant in order to reach $O_k$ and that would have to be small I guess (but because we handcraft $\hat H$ I guess that's fine).

Comment: $e_k$ are the eigenvalues??

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, yes.

Comment: Why should a generic state be a linear combination of eigenstates of an operator with the coefficients being the eigenvalues? It can't be--it is only a specific state. Also, since you are working in the Schrödinger picture, the coefficients would depend on time, not the eigenbasis. So, a generic state would be $\sum_k c_k(t) | O_k\rangle$ not $\sum_k e_k | O_k(t)\rangle$. Your question is not answered or made moot via this technical correction but I think it is useful to clarify it. The answer to your question is negative as explained by Chiral Anomaly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, the attractor idea doesn't work, because time evolution is unitary.

In more detail, the equation
$$
 i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|\Psi(t)\rangle
 =\hat H(t)|\Psi(t)\rangle
\tag{1}
$$
implies that the inner product between any two given solutions is independent of time:
$$
 \frac{d}{dt}\langle\Psi_1(t)|\Psi_2(t)\rangle = 0.
\tag{2}
$$
This is called **unitarity**, and it rules out the attractor idea.

Intuitively, unitarity says that time evolution can't make an initially uniform distribution of state-vectors in the Hilbert space cluster toward the basis vectors in any given orthonormal basis, not even slightly. Unitarity says that an initially uniform distribution remains uniform forever.

To put a little more detail behind this intuition, consider one of the eigenstates $O_k$ of the measured observable, and consider some small neighborhood of this eigenstate in the Hilbert space. By *small* neighborhood, I mean a neighborhood in which every state-vector $\psi$ is approximately proportional to $O_k$, in the sense that the component of $\psi$ orthogonal to $O_k$ has a much smaller norm than the component of $\psi$ that is proportional to $O_k$. Since unitarity preserves inner products, if we run this neighborhood backward in time arbitrarily far, all of those state-vectors will *still* be in a small neighborhood of (a past version of) the eigenstate $O_k$. But the overwhelming majority of the state-vectors in the Hilbert space are *not* in a small neighborhood of any of the basis vectors in any given orthogonal basis, so the overwhelming majority of the state-vectors in the Hilbert space are not in any basin of attraction.

Here's an analogy: A unitary transformation in Hilbert space is essentially the complex-valued version of a rigid rotation in (many-dimensional) Euclidean space. The fact that a rigid rotation preserves angles is not compatible with the attractor idea.

Comment: Aren't hermitian hamiltonian just a convenient convention that make time evolution unitary ? Why do we _require_ time evolution to be unitary ? Clearly measurement is **not** so why can't we adapt Schrödinger's equation to allow non unitary time evolution ?

Comment: @Narsilou Good question. This is simpler in the Heisenberg picture, where time parameterizes observables and not states. Then the question is simply: can we find an observable (at any time) with the property that almost all state-vectors are in a small neighborhood of one of its eigenstates? The answer is no, not unless the observable is trivial (proportional to the identity operator), because observables are _linear_ operators in quantum theory. People have tried to invent non-linear theories to implement the attractor idea, but (by definition) they're not called quantum theory anymore.

Comment: @Narsilou In the Schrodinger picture, you can see the fact that the time evolution operator has to be unitary as long as you grant two basic postulates: time-translational symmetry (there is no preferred $t=0$) and that quantum mechanics is a linear theory. This is the famous Wigner theorem and it is beautifully proven in an appendix of Chapter $2$ of Weinberg's Quantum Theory of Fields, Vol. 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answers I'll try to look into it @ChiralAnomaly Do you have references or keywords to those non-linear theories for attractor idea ? Google never led me to anything satisfactory to me.

Comment: @Narsilou You can try starting with the "GRW theory": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghirardi%E2%80%93Rimini%E2%80%93Weber_theory.